# Remove white modal image background

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have an image that is showed in a modal. Unfortunately this image has a white background.
Only the image should be shown and the white shouldn't be visible.
[image: modal with white background]

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal"><div id="close">X</div><img id="modalimg" class="modal-content" src=""></div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-content {
  max-height: 850px;
  max-width: 1700px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#myModal{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: none;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

JS (if needed):

```
$('.gallery-img').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').css('display', 'block');
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.modal-content').attr('src', src);
    $('.modal-content').data('src', src);
});
$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Edit:
Second picture for comparison:
[image]

Edit 2:
Code Pen: [Link](https://codepen.io/manuel-rahm/pen/BamyEJW)

Comment: Do you mean the shite background is part of the image? You need to crop the image, the code cannot detect the white background and not show it (well, technically you could but that's a huge challenge versus cropping the image)

Comment: @StudioTime No ,the white background is not part of the image, the white background is automatically created and it depends on the width and height of an image how large the white background is. You can't see the white background if the image covers it.

Comment: Can you add a working sandbox?

Comment: @ShivamSharma Never heard of a sandbox. What can it do?

Comment: @Rahm6 Sandbox is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, You can use StackOverflow's ["Code Snippet"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) opinion too.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Thanks, added the code pen for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a transparent background color.

```css
.modal-content {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only had to add !important to it and it worked. How does it inherit background color?

Comment: Just replace the `background-color: #fff` in your original css, then you won't need an `!important`.

Comment: Already did that, didn't work either. I guess it inherits from somewhere.

Comment: You're right, I just checked the codepen. Those are the jquery image gallery styles. You could work with CSS specificity and add an additional class `custom-modal-content` and define the style based on this selector `.custom-modal-content { background-color: transparent }`.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, many thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.modal-backdrop {
   background: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, as the modal isn't really bootstrap.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.